# multi-layer TIFF import broken in Pillow 6.1.0

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have been using Pillow 5.4.1 to import a multi-layer TIFF into Python. After upgrading to Pillow 6.1.0 the import no longer works and crashes the Python kernel. This happens whenever you try to extract the image data from the Image object, for example into a numpy array.

The image is:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=11UotufYYdNyjLmI_dcxtlM2l3xlT7mDw

The TIFF image is generated from commercial software. The first image is 8bit data compressed with LZW, the second image is 32bit floating point compressed with 'Adobe deflate', and the third image is 8bit compressed with LZW. I am attempting to extract the different images as follows:

```
# Python 3.7

import PIL
import numpy as np

image_stack = []

with PIL.Image.open('image.tif') as image:

    for i in range(2):

        image.seek(i)

        image_stack.append(np.array(image))
```

The precise error message changes depending on the slice you access, but errors include:

```
LZWDecode: Wrong length of decoded string: data probably corrupted at scanline 0.
LZWDecode: Bogus encoding, loop in the code table; scanline 0.
LZWDecode: Not enough data at scanline 0 (short 1168351 bytes).
```

I have traced the issue to the _load_libtiff function in tiffimageplugin.py. The line:

```
n, err = decoder.decode(b"fpfp")
```

returns err = -9, and this seems to cause the crash. However I can't work out how to fix this error.

The image headers are read correctly, it is just accessing the images themselves that causes the problems. Is this an issue with updates to Pillow or is the tiff file I am opening non-standard? As this code works with Pillow 5.4.1 I imagine it is an issue with the update to 6.1.0, but cannot find the root cause myself.

Comment: Works for me on Windows. Maybe Pillow is linked to a bad or outdated version of libtiff? FWIW, the second page is uncompressed and the import should be `from PIL import Image`.

Comment: Thanks for the testing, that's interesting, I've tried both Windows 7 and 10. On both I have a fresh Anaconda install, libtiff 4.0.10, Pillow 6.1.0, are they the same as yours? That's useful to know, and thought I'd leave it general to avoid confusion!

Comment: Pillow 6.1.0 crashes Python with segmentation fault on my Mac with your code. Works fine with 5.4.1. I use `libtiff` 4.0.10 with both.

Comment: I guess I was just lucky. The code crashes for me on Python 3.6, 3.8, and 3.7 32-bit, but not 3.7 64-bit...

Comment: Looks like a bug in Pillow. An uninitialized value is used for RowsPerStrip if the tag is not present.

Comment: I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/4034)

Comment: That's great, thanks, I assume this will be fixed in the next release then? Can I accept this as an answer?

Comment: In the meantime, try the binaries at https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow

Comment: @Will can the image be included as a test image in Pillow, under the Pillow license?

Comment: @radarhere Yes it can be included in the test library, I have asked and this is OK with the software owner.

Comment: Pillow 6.2.0 has now been released with the fix.